# Learning C#, Math equation not resulting as expected

Tags: c#, math

Learning C#, Math equation not resulting as expected.
This is apart of my homework. I do not understand why the result are not coming out as them should..

First equation

```
m=2
n=1

int sideA = (m^2) - (n^2);
```

result **-3**

Second equation

```
x1=2
x2=7

float Xmid = (x1 + x2)/2;
```

result **4**

Comment: What results do you expect?  You also realize `^` is a bitwise operator, not an exponent, correct?

Answer (score 11):

This is because in C# `^` means [`XOR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), not "raised to the power of". To square a number, use

```
Math.Pow(x, 2)
```

or simply

```
x * x
```

Also dividing integers truncates the fractional part. Use `decimal`, `double`, or `float` to get 3.5 as the midpoint of 3 and 4:

```
float x1=2
float x2=7

float Xmid = (x1 + x2)/2;
```

Comment: See the [**^ Operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) documentation and full list of [**C# Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Comment: @user2817395 You are welcome! If your program is working, consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer to your question, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Your first line of code:

```
int sideA = (m^2) - (n^2);
```

Is basically `m XOR 2` minus `n XOR 2`.  XOR is a bitwise operator that results in the bits where one is true but not both.  For more information on the *exclusive OR* operator, consult [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).  If you're trying to raise `m` to the *power of* `2`, try something like:

```
int sideA = Math.Pow(m, 2) - Math.Pow(n, 2);
```

Your second line of code:

```
float Xmid = (x1 + x2)/2;
```

Is `(2 + 7)` which is `9`, divided by *the integer* `2` which is 4.5, *however* because dividing an integer by another integer will *always* result in an integer, only the integer portion of the result will be kept.  The fact that you're assigning this expression to a `float` is irrelevant.

You might want to try:

```
float Xmid = (x1 + x2)/2.0;
```

or:

```
float Xmid = (x1 + x2)/2f;
```

*or* declare `x1` and `x2` as floats, both which will yield `4.5`.